# Inkscape fails to open .eps

Tags: inkscape

I need to automate conversion EPS -> SVG. When I open the .eps file from the GUI, it works. When I use the commandline with the -l parameter, it gives me this error:

```
parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
...
(inkscape.exe:8152): WARNING **: 11:18:12.747: Specified document ... cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)
```

But it shouldn't be trying to parse an SVG file when it has the .eps extension. Why does Inkscape fail to do it correctly when done from the CLI but works when done through the GUI?

Comment: What's the command that you're currently using?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I have tried .\Inkscape SOURCEFILE -l TARGETFILE and .\Inkscape SOURCEFILE -e TARGETFILE. Neither of those worked.

Comment: Which platform are you on? And why are you using `.\Inkscape`? And did you mistakenly use I (uppercase of i) instead of l (lowercase of L)?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy No, it did try to open the correct file because it printed the first line of the file I had in mind when it complained that the file cannot be parsed. I'm using .\Inkscape because I'm using powershell.

Comment: If it did print the first line of the file, then maybe your file is corrupt. I don't see any other reason for it. Did you try supplying other file of the same type?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I already wrote in the post that it works through the gui. How could the file be corrupt if it works that way?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to open EPS files I needed to get ghostscript and then add it to the PATH variable.
Then instead of using -l TARGETFILE parameter, I used --export-filename=TARGETFILE.
Now it works.

Comment: Why/how it worked in the GUI when you don't have Ghostscript already installed?

Comment: @Navaro I know that's weird and I have absolutely no idea.